# How can I DRY up JPA column definitions repeated in many entities?

Tags: jpa

I have multiple tables with UPDATE_TIME and INSERT_TIME columns that must be managed by application code.  Is there a way to avoid repeating the column definitions and behavior in every Entity class?  Specifically I want to somehow factor the column definitions and @PrePersist/@PreUpdate methods.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="THINGS")
public class Thing {
  // ... other columns ...
  @Column(name = "INSERT_TIME")
  private Date insertTime;

  @Column(name = "UPDATE_TIME")
  private Date updateTime;

  @PrePersist
  protected void onCreate() {
    insertTime = new Date();
  }

  @PreUpdate
  protected void onUpdate() {
    updateTime = new Date();
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to use [@MappedSuperclass](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/) ? Then you just make your `Thing` class inherit from the MappedSuperclass one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `@MappedSuperclass` (cf [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/)):

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class CommonThing {
  @Column(name = "INSERT_TIME")
  private Date insertTime;

  @Column(name = "UPDATE_TIME")
  private Date updateTime;

  @PrePersist
  protected void onCreate() {
    insertTime = new Date();
  }

  @PreUpdate
  protected void onUpdate() {
    updateTime = new Date();
  }
}
```

And then :

```
@Entity
public class Thing extends CommonThing {
    // Other columns.
}
```

From the documentation API, `@MappedSuperclass` also handles annotations such as `@PrePersist`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure that the lifecycle-methods will work, but you could try to use `Embeddable`s:

```
@Embeddable
public class Trace {

    @Column(name = "INSERT_TIME")
    private Date insertTime;

    @Column(name = "UPDATE_TIME")
    private Date updateTime;

    @PrePersist
    protected void onCreate() {
        insertTime = new Date();
    }

    @PreUpdate
    protected void onUpdate() {
        updateTime = new Date();
    }
}

@Entity
public class Thing {
    @Embedded
    private Trace trace;
    //more stuff
}

@Entity
public class OtherThing {
    @Embedded
    private Trace trace;
    //other stuff
}
```

This way you don't need to introduce a separate superclass for your entites. The `table` corresponding to any `Entity` that uses this `embeddable` needs to have the columns `INSERT_TIME` and `UPDATE_TIME` defined. You can use `@AttributeOverride` to override these column names if needed.

Comment: per JPA documentation, this does "not work for all providers".  Practically there is only Hibernate.

Comment: Ok, the safest would then be to place the lifecycle method in the classes that embed `Trace`..

Comment: that puts me back where I started -- with repeated code.  Your solution is good, because Hibernate is virtually the only JPA provider.

Comment: There are a few other that are quite good, and there is definitly room for improvement in Hibernate (there are JPA providers that are a lot faster than Hibernate..) The question is rather how often would you change a persistence provider, and I think the answer lies somewhere in the region of "never". And if it happens, changing this is probably not a huge task..